# EF Code First One-To-One with Join Table

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, one-to-one, join

I am trying to configure my model to an existing database, and am running into a problem.  The previous developer modeled a one-to-one relationship using a join table.  If I have the following classes and database structure below, how can I map this using code first?

```
public class Title {
 public Property Property { get; set; }
}

public class Property {
 public Title TitleInsurance { get; set; }
}


tbTitle
-TitleID = PK

tbPropertyToTitle
-TitleID - FK to tbTitle.TitleID
-PropertID - FK to tbProperty.PropertyID

tbProperty
-PropertyID = PK
```

Answer (score 0):

Code in VB.Net here, but should be easy to translate. Mark primary keys with the `Key` data attribute. Entity Framework will automatically look for properties named Class + ID, i.e. tbTitleID to assign as primary keys, but since that isn't applicable here, we need the `Key` attribute.

`Overridable` properties denote Navigation Properties. In C#, this should be equivalent to `Virtual` properties. When this navigation property is accessed, Entity Framework will automatically look for valid foreign key relations, and populate the appropriate data.

For a one-to-one relationship, Entity Framework expects that your two tables share the same primary key, as shown by TitleID here.

```
Public Class tbTitle
    <Key()>
    Public Property TitleID As Integer
    ...
    Public Overridable Property Property As tbProperty
End Class


Public Class tbProperty
    <Key()>
    Public Property TitleID As Integer
    ...
    Public Overridable Property Title As tbTitle
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the fluent API, I don't see any way to map one to one relations through a join table.  You might be able to fake it by setting it up as a many to many but then you would need a bit of extra code to ensure that your relation collections only ever have one item in them.